# Nsdictionary filtering using nspredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nspredicate

I'm trying to filter an `NSDictionary` using `NSPredicate`. There seems to be an error.

I have this `NSDictionary`:

```
dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:translation, @"trans", meaning, @"mean", pronounce, @"pron", theId, @"id", nil];
```

I want to filter this dictionary. If the value for `id` key in the dictionary is equal to `passedId`, add it to an `NSArray`:

I'm using following code:

```
NSPredicate *filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"theId == %@", passedId];
NSArray *requiredRows = [[dict allKeys] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filterPredicate];
```

Gives me this error:

```
'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFConstantString 0xada8> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key theId.
```

Comment: @iMani, what about the first line of code?

Answer (score 0):

Your key is `id`:

```
theId, @"id",
```

So your predicate is using the wrong key. It should be:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == %@", passedId]
```

because the key in the dictionary and predicate must match.

---

I didn't originally notice you using `[dict allKeys]`. This gets an array of all of the keys from one dictionary. There are no values there and there is no point filtering it.

You should have an array of dictionaries and be running the predicate on that array. Then the result will contains only dictionaries which match the `id`.

Comment: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key id.'

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not make sense at all. Split it into more lines to make it obvious:

```
NSPredicate *filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"theId == %@", passedId];
NSArray *allKeys = [dict allKeys];
NSArray *requiredRows = [allKeys filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filterPredicate];
```

allKeys is an array of NSStrings and it looks like this `@"id",
@"mean", @"pron", @"trans"`. You can't filter that for `@"theId"`, because the filtering will basically call `[NSString theId]` for each NSString and the result of this method will be compared with the string you have specified in the predicate. That's where the exception comes from, NSString does not have a method named `theId`.

And even if that would work because you use `self == %@` as predicate, the only result you would get back would be `@"theId"`.

I'm not sure what you really want, but it won't work like this.